# Add drawing objects to UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Basic question - I have a UIWebView with a pdf document loaded.

How can I add drawing objects (eg. a symbol) to this UIWebview's scrollView layer.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by accessing the UIWebViews UIScrollView using

```
UIScrollView *myWebScrollView = [[myWebView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

I can add objects to this layer. In combination with Mithin's [solution](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/) for hooking onto Tap-events, it allows full control of the content ...

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tiny4.org"]]];
    UIScrollView* scrollView =  [[web subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    web.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 100, 20)];
    label.text = @"testasdasdasda";
    [window addSubview:label];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:web];
}
```

Comment: hmmmm, thanks, but doesn't quite get me where I want to go. This adds the label to the window.What I need to do is to place objects on the web-view in a way that allows the objects to move with the content when the WebView is zoomed or scrolled